# In sequelize updateattributes method can update only one attribute in a table?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I tried(sequelize model) to update the values in the table, but it will update the only one value in the table.check the below example

```
employee.updateAttributes({first_name : value.first_name},
            {last_name : value.last_name},
            {email : value.email},
            {password : value.password},
            {phone : value.phone}
            ).on('success',function(employee){
    message.message = "Employee updated successfully";
    message.employee = employee;
    message.successMessage = "Success";
    callback(message);
})
```

Comment: What version of `sequelize` are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should provide a single object

```
employee.updateAttributes({
  first_name : value.first_name,
  last_name : value.last_name,
  email : value.email,
  password : value.password,
  phone : value.phone
})
```

Answer (score 2):

use .update() in lieu of .updateAttributes()

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone else comes across this...since it is one of the first results: while it's true the latest version of sequelize doesn't have updateAttribute(), using update() will work but you can't pass it an array if you have a hasMany association. rather, you must iterate like so:

```
user.Addresses.forEach((oldAddress, i) => {
    oldAddress.update(newAddresses[i])
});
```

Comment: This helped for hasMany relationship